# add referenced libraries to svn

Tags: svn, google-code

I am using google code project svn server and when I check out project all referenced libraries are gone. Is there a way to check out the libraries also?

To make the question clearer, I can't commit the referenced libraries either. In other words, there is no way to upload them to the server.

Comment: How are they referenced?

Comment: If they are in the svn server also, they should be in your machine when you check out the project root. What is the path of referenced libraries and your project; what did you check out? I think there should be more detail to answer.

Comment: I have used the external jar option and added an external jar that is situated out side the project in some other folder. The external library is not on the svn server and this is exactly the problem I want to solve.

Comment: @Jack Stevens when you 'check out' the project from SVN server to get the external libraries, you should commit them first. I still don't get the actual problem actually.

Comment: The problem is that there is no option to commit the referenced libraries. On every file in the project I have 'team' option in eclipse, but when I right click on the referenced library I don't have this option.

Comment: @Jack Stevens is there SVN plugin like subclipse set up on your Eclipse. If that is the case and if your project in Eclipse under SVN control there should be question marks for external files meaning that files that are not added to version control yet.

Comment: I use the standard SVN plugin that eclipse provide in the 'Install new Software', and using the Google code hosting. As you can see in this picture there are no question marks, or any other SVN mark: [link](http://i51.tinypic.com/350o191.jpg)

Comment: @Jack Stevens well I always use Subclipse with Eclipse. It is also be installed from Install New Software feature. Its update site is: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x  That plugin shows status of files in the project whether it is committed, updated, etc. It may be more informative about what's going on

Comment: Thanks suat for your help, I will try it. Its a same that it isn't possible through the ordinary SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

Are these common libraries such as Apache Commons, or Apache POI for example? Are available on a Maven repository?

Maybe your should consider using Maven to manage your dependencies. This system allows you to only manage your code and all needed dependencies can be automatically downloaded when one checks out your projects, reducing the amount of stuff you have to place on your repository :)

Comment: I am using JBoss Netty external jar.